# Regex matching a multi-line pattern

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a log file `test_list.txt` that looks like this:

```
Processing SampleDocumentController#index (for 101.101.101.101 at 2020-12-12 12:00:00) [POST]
  Session ID: sdfgs923jks0dm23mlasf3da9asfjvyur
  Parameters: {"format"=>"xml", "controller"=>"sample_document", "q"=>"last_updated_at", "action"=>"index"}
Completed in 0.00529 (189 reqs/sec) | Rendering: 0.00007 (1%) | DB: 0.00126 (23%) | 200 OK [https://www.bars.com/sample/sample_document.lmx?]
```

I have a regex to capture the method and the session id of the log file:

```
regex = /\[([A-Z]+)\]\D+([a-zA-Z0-9]{32}$)/i
```

When I run it individually, it works fine and returns the captured string `"POST"` and `"sdfgs923jks0dm23mlasf3da9asfjvyur"`. However, with the following script `test.rb`:

```
File.open("test_list.txt").each do |li|
  if !li.nil?
    x = li.match(regex)
    if !x.nil?
      a, b = x.captures
      p a
      p b
    end
  end
end
```

Running `ruby test.rb` in the command line does not print anything.

Any idea why it doesn't work with the script?

Comment: You seem to be reading the file line by line. Read it in as a single string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sawa is right.  I think you misunderstood the the `String#match`, which you usually want to use in a boolean context.

You probably want to use [scan](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/String.html#method-i-scan).  In your case you can scan it like this:

```
string = File.read("test_list.txt")
        p string.scan(/(\[[A-Z]+\])|((?<=Session ID: )[a-zA-Z0-9]{33})/)
```

which will result in something like this:

```
[["[POST]", nil], [nil, "sdfgs923jks0dm23mlasf3da9asfjvyur"]]
```

You can play around with the [expression on regular](https://rubular.com/r/VYkelphjP3ylVp)

Comment: Slurping a log file? This can be sloooooooow.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I hear you, I'm still trying to come up with a better way to do this.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev thank you, it worked like a charm! Btw the regex in my question is only a chunk of my actual regex expression for capturing all the values I need for a log file entry. My actual regex has 12 capture groups. I tried both 'scan' and 'match' after I passed the .txt file as a string (as you suggested) and it captured all the values. Now I need to come up with a way to parse each of those values to put them inside a database :)

Comment: @C.N.N. you probably mean myself :D.  Anyways, I'm glad that it helped

Comment: @SergioTulentsev that will depend on the log size and if reasonable log rotating is in place it won't be that bad.

Comment: @tukan oh yeah my bad, I was referring to you. Thanks a bunch mate :)

Answer (score 3):

It is because your regex matches only when both the method and the session id are present. In your log file, they are located on different lines, and none of the lines includes both. Hence, none of the lines matches the regex.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Thanks for the comment. Though, it looks like it is a matter of style: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/quantifiers/no-none-and-none-of. I prefer to stick with the formal one.

Comment: That's fair enough

Comment: @sawa thanks! I feel like I owe you a ton for always helping me out. I'll let you know if I get it right!

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work exactly as I wanted by doing this:

```
string = File.read("test_list.txt")
regex = /\[([A-Z]+)\]\D+([a-zA-Z0-9]{32}$)/

string.scan(regex).each do|x|
  puts x
end
```

If say, I only wanted to print a specific capture group, I just add the array index number for x:

```
puts x[0]
```

or

```
puts x[1]
```